# What does "flâneur recherché" translate to?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, traduction

As the title says, I'm trying to figure out what "flâneur recherché" means. I don't know the first word but I'm fairly sure the second word is research.

Comment: Welcome to French Language Nicholas Carlson. When you quote  please give context and if you say you do not know a word then say where you looked for it and what it is you do not understand in the definition given by the dictionary. Please visit the help centre and the [Asking](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without context. By definition a 'flâneur' does not do much: it could be someone taking a stroll in a park, or a student not paying attention at school. 'Recherché' may mean 'wanted (by the police)', 'popular' (wanted by a lot of people), 'elaborate'.

Comment: That helps a lot. Thank you very much!